# Jquery UI : Autocomplete Multiple Values, What That search.php Does?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This Jquery UI is really what I need : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote but after looking to its source code, I was wondering what that search.php in this line does?

```
source: function( request, response ) {
$.getJSON( "search.php", {
term: extractLast( request.term )
}, response );
},
```

I don't see any documentation about that search.php and I believe by having just MySQL SELECT like this on search.php isn't enough. because I think that jQuery UI is reading in JSON format. not plain MySQL result like this :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SomeTable");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    *** I don't know what to do about this data, I think it should be converted 
    *** into JSON format. but how?
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**another problem** with this autocomplete from jQuery UI is user is able to edit the autocomplete result and submitted to the server. for example if I type 'ca' on the demo page and choose 'Cattle Egret'. I still can edit that result into like this 'Catle Eret'.

how to 'lock' the jQuery UI result so user can't edit it but can be deleted? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there wouldn't be any info on search.php because that depends on how you're doing your search. but it should contain an SQL SELECT-like statement!

You can simply output some columns of your query like this:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = row['interesting_column'] ;
    // you can of course output multiple comlumns if you're interested in them
}

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

This should return an JSON array containing the columns from the db.